# How to solve $\log_{10}(x-1)<\frac{1}{\ln10}$

Tags: real-analysis

How to solve $\log_{10}(x-1)<\frac{1}{\ln10}$?

WolframAlpha says that the solution is $1<x<1+e$ but how do you get it?

Comment: $\frac1{\ln10}=\log_{10}e$

Comment: Note that $10=e^{\ln 10}\implies 10^{1/\ln 10}=e$.

Comment: @Minz So the solution should be $x<1+e$?

Comment: Looking at the original inequality should tell you why $x>1$ is also necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $${{\log }_{10}}\left( x-1 \right)=\frac{\ln \left( x-1 \right)}{\ln \left( 10 \right)}$$